# qt5 error on setting the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: qt5

Why am I getting this error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH'
```

on running this command

```
kv@kv:~/catkin_ws$ set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/Qt/5.5/gcc_64)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? That doesn't look like bash syntax. Did you mean: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$HOME/Qt/5.5/gcc_64"`?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$HOME/Qt/5.5/gcc_64" my-src-dir/
```